# How to integrate Lightning Calendar (Thunderbird) with KDE?

Tags: kde, thunderbird, calendar

I would like the KDE Calendar widget to display the calendar events from my [egroupware](https://www.egroupware.org/en/) calendar ([Caldav](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CalDAV)) which I have configured in Thunderbird. The server uses [TLS client certificate authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#Client-authenticated_TLS_handshake) which is not supported in [KOrganizer](https://kde.org/applications/office/org.kde.korganizer), even though well voted for respective bugs exist since 2006. Therefore, I cannot directly connect the calendar to KOrganizer.

PS: Kubuntu 21.10, Plasma 5.22.5, Thunderbird 91.5, but all this should be rather irrelevant

Update 1:
I have managed to create an .ics file calendar in Lightning that is accessible to KDE. if someone tells me how to synchronize **locally** two calendars in lightning that would be a complete solution. Alternatively, if I could automate exporting from Lightning to an ics file (overwriting the old one), this would also be a complete solution.

Update 2:
On gnome there is this fantastic thunderbird add-on:
https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-us/thunderbird/addon/eds-calendar-integration/reviews/